# SQLSyntaxError creating table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am receiving an error when creating my SQL table and I am unsure why.

```
CREATE TABLE 'Weights' {
ImageID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
Weight1 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight2 double(15,13) NOT NULL,                
Weight3 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight4 double(15,13) NOT NULL,               
Weight5 double(15,13) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY(ImageID)
);
```

> The error is : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''Weights' { ImageID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT
>   NULL, Weight1 double(15,' at line 1

Can anyone help?

Comment: I removed tags java and jdbc. This question is not related to java

Comment: Sorry they are still included from the last time I posted!

Answer (score 1):

- Don't put your table name in quotes.
- You opened with `{` instead of `(`.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Weights (
  ImageID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  Weight1 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
  Weight2 double(15,13) NOT NULL,                
  Weight3 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
  Weight4 double(15,13) NOT NULL,               
  Weight5 double(15,13) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY(ImageID)
  );
  ```

Comment: Too much switching between Java and SQL.. Thank you! I have fixed this issue but I am still receiving the same error :(

Comment: I removed the marks around the Table Name and its working now!

Comment: @Sfitz12173 Good Job. I included that into my Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it's 100% Working

```
CREATE TABLE 'Weights' (
ImageID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
Weight1 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight2 double(15,13) NOT NULL,                
Weight3 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight4 double(15,13) NOT NULL,               
Weight5 double(15,13) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY(ImageID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your squiggly brace should be a parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE Weights (
ImageID int(3) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
Weight1 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight2 double(15,13) NOT NULL,                
Weight3 double(15,13) NOT NULL,
Weight4 double(15,13) NOT NULL,               
Weight5 double(15,13) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY(ImageID)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52123b2